# Overloading Menu Items in Mapview on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, menu, android-mapview

1 ) I am trying to add my custom menus to the menu list of MapView and unable to do so.

2 ) And Is it possible to push Mapview on a screen Manager.

```
Say pushScreen(MapView instance)
```

Can anyone help me on these issues please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Mapview open instance of Blackberry Maps. So to add menu on Blackberry Maps we need to take help of ApplicationMenuItem which add menus to native Blackberry apps.

2- You cannot push Mapview instance.